# javascript peformance on string concatenation

Tags: javascript

I read this [article](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html) about javasccript performance on string concatenation and scope variable so I rewrote some of my code the way it was suggested but **the recommended way is MUCH slower**. I'm testing using Chrome and IE: similar conclusion.

Basically, I have an object that contains strings and I'm loop through each value to generate HTML. The two ways I'm comparing are doing:

```
var TheHTML = "";
TheHTML = TheHTML + ...;
```

and the other way is using an array and join

```
TheHTML[i++] = ....;
```

**I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YKvAQ/).** The code I'm using looks like this:

```
var ObjectTest = {};

ObjectTest.Key1 = "The Key 1";
ObjectTest.Key2 = "The Key 2";
ObjectTest.Key3 = "The Key 3";
ObjectTest.Key4 = "The Key 4";
ObjectTest.Key5 = "The Key 5";

function TestSpeed() {

    var TheHTML1 = "";
    var THeHTML2 = "";

    var TheStart1 = new Date().getTime();
    for (var TestPerf1 = 0; TestPerf1 < 100000; TestPerf1++) {

        TheHTML1 = "";
        TheHTML1 = TheHTML1 + '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTest.Key1 + '</div>';
        TheHTML1 = TheHTML1 + '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTest.Key2 + '</div>';
        TheHTML1 = TheHTML1 + '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTest.Key3 + '</div>';
        TheHTML1 = TheHTML1 + '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTest.Key4 + '</div>';
        TheHTML1 = TheHTML1 + '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTest.Key5 + '</div>';
        TheHTML1 = TheHTML1 + '<br><br>';

    }
    document.getElementById('TestOutput1').innerText = new Date().getTime() - TheStart1;
    document.getElementById('Output1').innerHTML = TheHTML1;


    var TheStart2 = new Date().getTime();
    var ObjectTestCopy = ObjectTest;

    for (var TestPerf2 = 0; TestPerf2 < 100000; TestPerf2++) {

        var Test = [];
        var i = 0;

        Test[i++] = '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTestCopy.Key1 + '</div>';
        Test[i++] = '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTestCopy.Key2 + '</div>';
        Test[i++] = '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTestCopy.Key3 + '</div>';
        Test[i++] = '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTestCopy.Key4 + '</div>';
        Test[i++] = '<div style="clear:both">' + ObjectTestCopy.Key5 + '</div>';
        Test[i++] = '<br><br>';

        TheHTML2 = Test.join("");
    }
    document.getElementById('TestOutput2').innerText = new Date().getTime() - TheStart2;
    document.getElementById('Output2').innerHTML = TheHTML2;
}

window.onload = function () { TestSpeed(); }
```

**Why is the suggested code slower?**

Comment: And what is your question? If the new code is slower, then use the old one again...

Comment: The first way is faster because it's emulating `array.join()` without an array.

Comment: @FelixKling Think it's a safe assumption that he's looking for an answer why...

Comment: In IE6 and IE7 the array join is faster when you're doing a lot of concatenation. It's pointless in newer browsers.

Comment: @SLaks: the test on fiddle shows the code is 20 times slower; would running it in jsperf make a significant difference?

Comment: @Pointy: even in IE7, it's the same.

Comment: Try it when your object has 300 keys and not just 5.  That's when it makes a difference.

Comment: @frenchie: It makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you read the ENTIRE article:

> However, browser string optimizations have changed the string concatenation picture.
>
> Firefox was the first browser to optimize string concatenation. Beginning with version 1.0, the array technique is actually slower than using the plus operator in all cases. Other browsers have also optimized string concatenation, so Safari, Opera, Chrome, and Internet Explorer 8 also show better performance using the plus operator. Internet Explorer prior to version 8 didn’t have such an optimization, and so the array technique is always faster than the plus operator.

Comment: But even with the recent browser optimizations, we're still talking about TWENTY TIMES SLOWER!

Comment: Really? Your test was only 2 times slower for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think it's slower because you're constantly updating the array. But from my own tests,

```
  var iable = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'].join('');
```

is faster than

```
  var iable = 'a'+'b'+'c'+'d'+'e'+'f';
```

Use loops to generate the code, not within the code itself.